# Website's url parameter gets returned onto page- can that be exploited?

Tags: web-application, url

I'm currently trying to find a vulnerability in a website (yes, I have permission). I found a url with a parameter that, when I change the text in it, that text is set as the name for the background image.
Ex. when I change the url parameter text to 'anytexthere', this is what the block of code will look like:

```
<div style="background-image: url('/images/logo-anytexthere.png')"></div>
```

Is it possible to exploit this? I've tried unicode brackets and normal HTML code, and the unicode/normal HTML brackets are just removed in the image name.

tldr; url parameter text gets returned into background image name in the page's code, but removes brackets/special characters. How can I exploit this?

Comment: Are single and double quotes removed?

Comment: @Arminius yes, they're both removed.

Comment: what about "`"?

Comment: @dandavis Out of curiosity - what would you do with backticks?

Comment: @Arminius: they are valid string delims in JS now, but if he can't find a way out of the attrib context, it likely doesn't matter.

Comment: @dandavis yes the backticks are removed

Comment: @dandavis Sure, but they wouldn't help inside a CSS string inside an HTML attribute, so leaving them would probably be fine.

Comment: Some rough ideas: If you had file inclusion abilities in this directory, and knew of a way to get this file to be interpreted as code, you could use it to run code on the domain.  However, I don't know of any way for a png file ending with ".png" that's referenced in the css to be executed as code by a browser/OS, but similar exploits have been found before.  If you had file inclusion abilities you could also use a custom background image to modify the website and mislead the user.

Comment: @CodyP thanks, unfortunately I don't have file inclusion abilities.

Comment: On another note though, I found out that putting an ampersand in the parameter makes the whole page blank. Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't use `'` and `"`, there is no way to get out of the CSS string context to achieve XSS.

If single quotes were allowed, you could have injected CSS attributes, e.g.:

```
'); color: red; /*
```

If double quotes were allowed, you could have injected an HTML attribute, e.g.:

```
" onmouseover="alert('Where is my bounty')
```

If angle brackets were allowed (but not quotes), you would still have no chance to inject custom HTML. Something like this does **not** trigger:

```
<div style="background-image: url('/images/logo-><script>alert(1)</script>.png')"></div>
```

So what you're left with is the ability to change the image path to any URL on the same domain. E.g.:

```
<div style="background-image: url('/images/logo-/../../favicon.ico?.png')"></div>
```

As you can guess, this has a very limited security impact. In the rare case that the site implements CSRF protection solely based on the `Referer` header, you might be able to use this for CSRF attacks. But otherwise, there is no obvious way to exploit this behavior.